# Output of the audio file when using wavfile.read() does not originate from zero

Tags: python, wav, audio-analysis

All of my audio files that I am using producing an output that does not make sense for me when using wavfile.read() I do not why.
For example output of one file is

[Example of the output of one of my audio files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1WvL.png)

why is it not originating from zero like a normal audio for instance :-

[example of a normal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xP0i.png)

I wanted to ask why my output in the first link is not read normally and how to display it normally so I can analysis the audio properly.
I have been searching for a couple of days and could solve it so I would appreciate it if someone can guide me or provide me with useful links

Comment: Does the waveform look normal when opened via Audacity or something?

Comment: Yea using Audacity not when using wavfile.read()

Comment: You should specify what format the audio files are in - sample rate, bit depth, stereo/mono, signed or unsigned, file type, and anything else relevant. This seems like an issue where the audio is being read in an incorrect format.

Comment: The format is WAV File (.wav), the sample rate is 16 kHz, Stereo. I tried to get the bit depth and whether its signed but could not see how to get it using wavfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it depends on the library that is reading the audio file which can produce different outputs, I shifted to read my audio files by:-

```
import soundfile as sf
data, samplerate = sf.read(audioFile)
```

and now the output representation is originating from zero.